# Is it possible to copy file from Android Mobile(internal or external storage) to Windows Destop/Mac via USB using programmatically?

Tags: android, windows, macos, usb-drive

Once the Android Mobile is connected to Windows Destop/Mac using USB cable, just want to copy file from Android device one path to System path programmatically on button click event.

Comment: In general it is possible, but you will have to develop a Windows/Mac application which will accept this file. Otherwise there is no way. That's because if any device could copy any file to the host PC, it was a huge security issue. Only host can copy files from/to device

Comment: Thanks, Without App on Windows/Mac from Android is any sdk for copy files to system

Comment: `Otherwise there is no way. That's because if any device could copy any file to the host PC, it was a huge security issue. Only host can copy files from/to device`